# Как попросить пользователя разрешение на использование геоданных?

Tags: java, android, геолокация

Обычно в приложениях вылетает AlertDialog c запросом на разрешение использования геоданных. Я хотел бы узнать как сделать то же самое в своем приложении :)
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: В сети есть много статей на эту тему: https://metanit.com/java/android/18.2.php

Comment: @Влад Сапожников Вас ведь именно диалоговое окно на разрешение интересует? а не сами пермишены ?

Comment: Нет,  именно пермишены

Answer (score 2):

Вы скорее всего говорите про *Runtime Permissions*, которые появились в *Android 6.0 (API level 23).*

Указываем в AndroidManifest.xml нужные нам пермишены.

```
// пермишн для локации по GPS
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
// пермишн для локации, используя сеть
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Запрос пермишена:

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 777;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            //показываем диалог
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Юзер одобрил
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            //запрашиваем пермишен, уже не показывая диалогов с пояснениями
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // пермишен получен можем работать с locationManager
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Request location updates:
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                }

            } else {

                //пермишен не был получее =(

            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Переопределим `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (checkLocationPermission()) {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

             //Request location updates:
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: А если API ниже 23, то как быть?